# Workspace для intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

В eclipse есть workspace, который хранит проекты.

Как создать workspace в intellij idea, чтобы в него также можно было бы помещать проекты? Ведь workspace это не просто директория, там должен потом появиться файл с конфигурацией, как я понимаю. Поэтому недостаточно просто создать папку и туда кинуть все проекты, нужно это сделать правильно. Но как? Подскажите

Comment: первый вопрос - для чего вам такой воркспейс?

Answer (score 1):

В idea настройки каждого проекта хранятся в папке `.idea`, которая находится в корне проекта. Каждый проект - отдельная сущность.

Когда открываешь папку с проектом, там создаётся папка `.idea`.

Не обязательно иметь какую-то общую папку, в которой должны быть все проекты. Idea работает с проектами, расположенными где угодно.

Comment: еще можно хранить в файле .ipr

Comment: Да, суть остаётся та же